# How do I load inital set of data with ajax call in React redux?

Tags: ajax, reactjs, redux

I have a problem with redux trying to load initial data with an asynchronous call to my backend API that returns a JSON. Right now, I'm trying to load a bunch of different articles, but I have no idea how to load it asynchronously. Since it is an initial set of data, should I load it synchronously? If yes, then how would I acheive a synchronous call to my API? If not, how would I go about solving this problem asynchronously?

Right now, I have static json data, `data/articles.js` that creates a default state in `store.js`.

Thanks

Comment: Alternatively to loading data when the app starts, consider shipping the data along with the page on page load. This can significantly speed up page startup. It could also be slower however, depending on how much data, how long the fetch takes on the backend, and also on whether it's possible for the user to use the app (partially) before data has asynchronously loaded or not.

Comment: If the data is not loaded, then the user really won't be able to do anything with the webapp.I think this is exactly what I want, ship the data on page load. How would I go about doing this? Thanks

Comment: Just get it on the backend while preparing the page. You can embed it using a script tag. You can load it with `createStore` on page load. You can even use Redux itself to generate the data on the server. You could get the data with `store.getState ()` and then ship it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use a [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) middleware, which allows you to dispatch async actions and a [fetch](https://github.com/matthew-andrews/isomorphic-fetch) library (for example) for downloading your initial data.

So:
1) create an action which fetch your data, example:

```
export function fetchData() {
  const options = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Client-ID xx' // if theres any needed
   }
  }

  return (dispatch) => {
    return fetch('yourUrl.json', options)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => dispatch(receiveYourData(data)))
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
 }
}
```

**receiveYourData** is a action which will place your data in your state, example:

```
export function receiveYourData (payload = []) {
  return {
    type: RECEIVE_DATA,
    payload: payload
  }
}
```

Of course you have to write action handler, which after dispatching an action, will place your data in your state.

If you have your setup (similar to above), you should dispatch **fetchData** in your componentDidMount lifecycle method (its one of the option of course :) ).

If you dont know how to do particular parts, you can refer to this [Example](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/ExampleRedditAPI.html).

Also [official async](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/tree/master/examples/async) example may be helpful :)

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, I sort of understand it now. I'll have to go through the example a couple times to fully understand it haha.

Comment: Where do you use componentDidMount? in the container or in the component itself?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem. It turned out that you have to add a lot of code for this simple task. So I simplified this process and created a package for async loading of initial state in redux - [redux-async-initial-state](https://github.com/KELiON/redux-async-initial-state).

You can check out examples and in your case in the end your store creator will look like this:

```
// Load initial state function
const loadStore = () => {
  return Promise(resolve => {
    fetch('/data/articles.js')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(resolve);
  });
}

const storeCreator = applyMiddleware(asyncInitialState.middleware(loadStore));
const store = storeCreator(reducer);
```